# Can I call a different html for mobile site? Based on width?

Tags: mobile, width

hopefully my questions won't be too vague.

I designed a pretty simple website. You can see an image of it >>> [here](http://oi50.tinypic.com/1z18th5.jpg)

But now I'm trying to make a mobile version.
However I'm contemplating using a different html for the mobile version since the desktop version has jquery pop-ups (prettyPhoto) and a very large backround that scales, which aren't great on mobile screens.

I'm unsure of how to do that. My first question therefore is:

**1.) How do I call a different html for mobile?**

Also, for tablets, the website renders pretty well in landscape mode but becomes weird in portrait mode. So my second question is:

**2.) Can this different html be called based on width? If so, any ideas how?**
So if tablet is viewing website in portrait mode, they get the mobile version, if they are seeing it in landscape mode, they get the desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are attempting to do, but from experience as both developer and mobile user, what you propose is not a good idea. Again, since you have not mentioned what you are attempting to do, I am speaking generally. Consistency is very important for UX, and delivering completely different behaviours and looks for orientation does not sound like a good usability. Also, remember that on today's tablets, switching orientations is very easy. Would you load each version on each orientation change? What if the user is on 3G?

But technically, it is possible to load depending on width or orientation. Use AJAX, and load the appropriate content.

Comment: I have not yet attempted anything because I wanted to find out what the optimal solution is. My background has a width of 2800px and is resized for screen width but it makes no sense to download that if viewing from a phone.

Also, as I said, my pop-ups don't render well on mobile screens. But I want to keep them for the desktop screens.

So I'm thinking I can either have a completely different site (same fonts and general design vibe but different layout) for phones, or maybe there's another more elegant solution?

Comment: You should use CSS media queries for loading mobile versions of your images:
http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/